# ATL is not working when migrating to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, atl, comobject

I have a project which uses an ATL component to create pie charts. It's working fine in Visual Studio 2010 but when I migrate it to Visual Studio 2015, its not working or not instantiated. It's crashing at runtime

1. I have installed VS 2015 with the C++ support on Windows 7.
2. I have set the platform toolset to v140.
3. I have installed the VS 2015 x86 redistributable package .
4. Target platform version 8.1.
5. Tried adding ATL support in existing MFC project by ATL wizard. This causes crash in ATL `(_pModule == 0)` and some Dlls also not registered due to this change so I had to revert the changes.

Answer (score -1):

Why do you add ATL again support?

As far as I understand your question this is an existing project and has ATL support! The ASSERT simply tells you that you have two ATL modules.

Comment: I found, function AtlAxGetControl() is returning NULL to IUnknown .